# API code not running correct query

Tags: javascript, mysql, api

I have been trying to get my website to call this API function, but it is calling the incorrect query, even though it is show correctly on my file.  The server side js code is as follows:

```
app.post('/createPhysician/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("below is the req body for createPhysician");
    console.log(req.body);

    var createPromise = interact.createPhysician(
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.lastName,
        req.body.yearNum,
        req.body.position,
        req.body.isAttending,
        req.body.highRiskTrained);

    createPromise.then(function(createResponse) {
        res.json("successful"); // returns the physicianID for the createUsers
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(req.body);
        res.json("Terrible job you botched it");
    }); 
});
```

The interact file that is calling the query is below:
var mysql = require('mysql');

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "dbName"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error:- ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected Id:- ' + con.threadId);
});


createPhysician: function(physicianID,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    yearNum,
    position,
    isAttending,
    highRiskTrained)  {

    var qry = "insert into Physician values (firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained \
    ('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', "+yearNum+", '"+position+"', '"+isAttending+"', '"+highRiskTrained+"');"
    return runQuery(qry);
}
```

when I run it with the following data in postman, I am getting an error for a field that is not even in my query anymore as seen.

API body:

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "yearNum": 1,
    "position": "coder",
    "isAttending": 1,
    "highRiskTrained": 0
}
```

postman error message:

```
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'undefined' in 'field list'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "insert into Physician (physicianID, firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained)             values (undefined, 'jane', 'doe', 1, 'coder', '1', '0');"
}
```

[image]

below is my runQuery code:

```
function runQuery(queryString) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        con.query(queryString, function (err, result, fields){
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please share table structure of Physician table

Comment: @Nikolaus in this instance it is saying the sql is trying to insert a value for `physicianId` when it is not actually in the SQL and is an auto populated key

Comment: If you want to get the Id generated, you have to define it in the table structure, otherwise you have to set it manually.

Comment: @Nikolaus I know, I already have, I am just unclear as to why a value that isn't in my insert statement in my code is showing up as in my sql statement in my API call error

Comment: @VarunChawla I have added my table description to my post

Comment: Can you show the runQuery-Code?

Comment: How is con.query defined?

Comment: I have updated the code to show that as well @Nikolaus

Comment: Did you try to insert null with physicianId?

Comment: yes I did @Nikolaus

Comment: Maybe it’s a issue of the MySQL-Package.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the SQL-syntax. Try this:

```
var qry = "insert into Physician (firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained) values ('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', "+yearNum+", '"+position+"', '"+isAttending+"', '"+highRiskTrained+"');";
```

Comment: isn't this the same exact thing as my sql?  I get the exact same issue with this code

Comment: I positioned the values-keyword differently. Did you try to insert an empty row?

Comment: I have tried that as well, it just adds and undefined value to the end of the query instead...

Comment: @Drew As I asked beneath your question, too, can you share the code of your runQuery function?

Comment: I have just added the code showing my runQuery function